# JspMethodNotFoundException: /login.jsp(40,26) > '#{login_bean.dbDelete}' Method not found

Tags: jsp, jsf

I am not able to invoke a method in a JSF backing bean. I am getting this error.

> (org.apache.jasper.el.JspMethodNotFoundException: /login.jsp(40,26)
>   '#{login_bean.dbDelete}' Method not found:
>   beans.login_bean@263b1d94.dbDelete() )

The method signature is below:

```
public void dbDelete(String UName) {
    // 
}
```

The JSP code calling the method is:

```
 <h:commandButton action="#{login_bean.dbDelete}" value="Delete" type="submit"/>
```

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: `beans.login_bean@263b1d94.dbDelete()` is a method signature with no params, which doesn't match up with your `dbDelete` method's signature.

Comment: I am not sure how to tackle this... !!!

Comment: This has at least completely nothing to do with MySQL. Please learn to think logically. How could whatever the method itself is doing ever cause that it's never been invoked? I edited your question to reduce irrelevant noise, so that we can better concentrate on the real problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<h:commandButton action="#{login_bean.dbDelete}" value="Delete" type="submit"/>
```

This action expects an argumentless method.

```
public void dbDelete() {
    // ...
}
```

So to fix this problem, either just remove `String UName` from your method signature, or provide a valid argument (works in EL 2.2 only):

```
<h:commandButton action="#{login_bean.dbDelete(uName)}" value="Delete" type="submit"/>
```

Comment: Thanks BalusC. I changed it now its not giving any error but the item is still not deleted. i could not find any other issues with this... Will check further..

Comment: This new problem is unrelated to the problem you initially had. Just press `Ask Question` to ask a new (and isolated!) question about this if you still stucks.

Comment: And thanks for editing my question for clarity. I follow your blog posts and trying to understand more, would you suggest a good reading resource which will take me from basics??

Answer (score 0):

what you are doing is :

```
delete * from tbl_users where UName=?
```

and your delete query syntax is wrong. remove star, it should be

```
delete  from tbl_users where UName=?
```

Look this http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-statement-example-delete-a-record/